# VBA/auto sorting help on EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am trying to put VBA code that makes it so that when I automatically input values into a table they are automatically sorted. It was working for some of the charts, but now only the last chart automatically sorts and none of the others do. I have attached my code. [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loXDx.png)

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as a screen cap

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim SortRange As Range
    Dim KeyRange As Range

    ' Set the range to be sorted
    Set SortRange = Me.Range("A2:C" & Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    ' Set the range that contains the sort key (e.g., column A)
    Set KeyRange = Me.Range("A2:A" & Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    ' Check if the changed range intersects with the sort range
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, SortRange) Is Nothing Then
        ' Disable events to prevent infinite loop
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    
        ' Sort the range based on the key range
        SortRange.Sort Key1:=KeyRange, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    
        ' Enable events again
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, whenever you enter new data within the specified range (A2:C), the worksheet will automatically sort based on the first column (column A).